# Integrating $\frac{\ln x^2}{e^{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I am stuck when trying to find
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x^2}{e^{x^2}}\,dx$$
The context of the question is asking if the integral is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Note that you do not have to actually compute anything to solve this problem! We are only interested in if the integral converges or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the explicit value, well,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}2\log(x)e^{-x^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto\sqrt{x}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{-1/2}\log(x)e^{-x}\,dx $$
equals $\frac{1}{2}\Gamma'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ by the dominated convergence theorem and the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function, together with the well known $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$. Since $\psi(1)=\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ and 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b},$$
by picking $a=\frac{1}{2}$, $b=1$ and rearranging we get
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\log(x^2)e^{-x^2}\,dx = \color{blue}{-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(\gamma+2\log 2)}$$
which is approximately $-\frac{7}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is equivalent to $2\ln{|x|}$ at $x$ goes to $0$ so is integrable there. 
The function is $o(e^{-|x|})$ as $|x|$ goes to infinity, so is integrable there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Near $0$, your function is equivalent to $\ln(x^2)=2 \ln(x)$ which is integrable.

Near $+\infty$, your function is a $o \left( \frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}} \right)$ which is integrable.